# unix script - unable to trap or interpret error code within sqlplus properly

Tags: oracle, unix, error-handling, sqlplus

I am trying to run a shell script (ksh) that runs oracle sqlplus to run a sql script in the background. Within the sql script I am using `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` to trap the error code so I can check it and exit my program, else continue to next sql statement.

I'm not sure if my problem is in my shell script trapping the error or the use of `WHENEVER`?
I am producing/invoking the `ORA-` error, but return code still shows as `Return_code=0,` (pass) and continues to run the next script. It should fail and exit the program.

Can someone help me configure this script properly? My `if-then-else` logic maybe flawed too. Thanks.

Here's my sql (whenever.sql) script to invoke error:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
begin
  SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Here's my script:

```
KEY=$BASEDIR/.keyinfo;
LOG=$BASEDIR/run_tst.log;

# Check before we run
if [ -f "$KEY" ]
then
IFS="
"
set -A arr $(cat $KEY)
echo "Running Test ===>$TIMESTAMP" >> $LOG 2>&1
/bin/sqlplus ${arr[0]}/${arr[1]} @whenever.sql &
pid1=$!
echo "Waiting for PID:$pid1" >> $LOG 2>&1
wait $pid1
ret=$?
echo "Return_code=$?"  >> $LOG 2>&1
if [ $ret !=0 ] #if not success
then
     exit $ret
     echo "Error found...Return_code=$?" >> $LOG 2>&1
     echo "Error found...exiting program ===>$TIMESTAMP" >> $LOG 2>&1
     exit 1
else
     /bin/sqlplus ${arr[0]}/${arr[1]} @tst2.sql
fi
else
   echo "key not found. Exiting.  ==>$TIMESTAMP" $LOG 2>&1
fi
exit 0
```

Results (Showing 0, since there is error, should be something else other than 0).

```
Running Test ===>20130825-09:25
Waiting for PID:6383
Return_code=0
```

I also tried `WHENENVER SQLERROR EXIT 1` and still getting same result of `Return_code=0`

Output from testing:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

  SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
./run.sh[38]: test: Specify a parameter with this command.
```

Comment: It could be that `sqlplus` always returns 0 (success) even when the SQL it executes fails.  I've known other SQL command interpreters work like that — and it makes them painful to use in shell scripts.  Maybe you should run the broken SQL directly from your `ksh` command line and look at `$?` immediately after `sqlplus` exits.  If it says 0, that is the problem.  If not, let me know and I'll remove this comment.

Comment: if i'm putting the script in the background using `&`, wouldn't I want to look for `$!` instead?

Comment: If you're running a script in background (with `&`), your only interest in `$!` (the background process's PID) is perhaps to wait for it to finish.  I don't think you can find the exit status of a background process in shell — though there might be a `bash` extension I've not noticed (discovered, searched for) to get it that I'm not aware of.  When you run something in background, you're saying "get on with; I don't care about the result", roughly. In your script, you barely need to use background. You run the process, report its PID, and then wait for it.

Comment: OK; I RTFM'd — can't you?  You can't run `wait $!` because of the C shell's baleful influence on `bash`.  But, you can capture `$!` in a variable: `x=$!` and then `wait $x`, and the exit status `$?` of the `wait` is the exit status of the background process.

Comment: There are 5 lines in your script illustrating it exactly, ending at `ret=$?`.  If the value of `$ret` is 0, that's because `sqlplus` exited with 0.  Have you done as I suggested and tested the return status from `sqlplus` when it is run as a regular foreground shell command but executes a failing SQL command?  I'm beginning to think it _will_ return 0...success...even when the SQL fails.  You'll have to check that; I don't have access to Oracle.

Comment: confirmed as you suggested. it will return 0 on a failiing SQL command if the sql statement is run in the foreground (removing the `&`).

Comment: Unless there's a way of making SQL*Plus exit with a non-zero status when an SQL command fails, then you are into extremely painful programming, groping through the output of the command to detect the meaningful errors.  Ugh! — speaking from experience with a similar program for a different DBMS. Actually, I decided over 20 years ago to write my own variant of the command line program precisely so I could get control over the exit status (and where the outputs went, and various other infelicities). So, I know the pain. Do look hard at the SQL*Plus manual; there is likely a way to exit on error.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yup.  There's a good reason my comments aren't an answer! Once you start finding bugs, there are usually lots lurking where the first is found.  The fragment `echo "Return_code=$?"  >> $LOG 2>&1
if [ $ret !=0 ] #if not success
then
     exit $ret
     echo "Error found...Return_code=$?" >> $LOG 2>&1
     echo "Error found...exiting program ===>$TIMESTAMP" >> $LOG 2>&1
     exit 1` has numerous problems.  The first and second echos should use `$ret` instead of `$?`; the test condition is malformed (`if [ $ret != 0 ]`); the `exit $ret` means the following echos are not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display your return code with this:

```
ret=$?
echo "Return_code=$?"  >> $LOG 2>&1
```

... the `$0` is now the result of the assignmment of `ret` on the previous line, not the earlier `sqlplus`, so it's always gping to be zero. You also have an early exit in the `if` block, and you won't see the messages after that, and your test condition is missing a space (and I prefer `-ne` to `!=`):

```
...
ret=$?
echo "Return_code=$ret"  >> $LOG 2>&1
if [ $ret -ne 0 ] #if not success
then
     echo "Error found...Return_code=$ret" >> $LOG 2>&1
     echo "Error found...exiting program ===>$TIMESTAMP" >> $LOG 2>&1
     exit $ret
else
...
```

I also prefer to enclose variables in braces, e.g. `${ret}`, but I guess that's a matter of taste unless there is ambiguity. You can also call `sqlplus` with a `-s` flag to hide the banners in the log, incidentally.

Comment: Got it. With your suggestions, I am able to capture the error now without returning code of 0. Since I am performing a `wait` because I have to make sure that script finishes, should I not check for `$!` inestead? thanks.

Comment: @jdamae - `$!` gives you the pid of the process you just put in the background, not its status; you're already using that to set `$pid` and when you `wait $pid`, and immediately after that the `$?` is the result of the process that was in the background. You already seem to know how to do that part, and that just `wait` or `wait $!` would not work. But as others have said, putting this in the background at all seems a bit pointless at the moment.

Comment: @jdamae - also be aware that `$ret` won't usually be exactly what you expect from `SQL.SQLCODE`; the return code from a command will be in the range 0-255, so it'll be the mod of the real value (which could actually be zero, I suppose). The details may be shell-specific, but be careful.

Comment: let me add that, i'm going to build on this. the reason why i was using `wait` is because I would eventually run 1 or more sql statements in parallel within this script, thus setting them each in the background. Once all those sql statements were complete, run one last one and the reason for my main question was in the case one of the sql statments had an error that I would exit the program all together.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `exit` at the end of your script:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
begin
  SELECT COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST FROM DUAL;
END;
EXIT;
```

EDIT: Assuming sqlplus returns the error code, try eliminating the background process in your script. It can be shortened to:

```
/bin/sqlplus ${arr[0]}/${arr[1]} @whenever.sql && /bin/sqlplus ${arr[0]}/${arr[1]} @another.sql || echo "Error..."
```

Comment: No luck. I tried adding that. Still getting the same result where it returns 0 in my logfile and continues to next script. I also go this in the output: `./run.sh[38]: test: Specify a parameter with this command.`

Comment: Getting close. Thanks. I managed to get out of the script upon error. Although, I'm still confused as to why return code is still the same. `Return_code=0`.